# parallel "Folding" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I have a function with type below:

```
union :: a -> a -> a
```

And `a` has **additivity** property. So we can regard `union` as a version of `(+)`

Say, we have `[a]`, and want to perform a parallel `"folding"`, for non-parallel foldling we can do only:

```
foldl1' union [a]
```

But how to perform it in parallel?
I can demonstrate problem on `Num` values and `(+)` function.

For example, we have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `(+)`
In parallel we should split

```
[1,2,3] (+) [4,5,6]
[1,2] (+) [3] (+) [4,5] (+) [6]
([1] (+) [2]) (+) ([3] (+) [4]) (+) ([5] (+) [6])
```

then each `(+)` operation we want to perform in parallel, and combine to answer

```
[3] (+) [7] (+) [11] = 21
```

Note, that we split list, or perform operations in any order, because of `a` additivity.

Is there any ways to do that using any standard library?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801351/more-generic-parfoldr-than-this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to generalize your `union` to any associative binary operator ⊕ such that (a ⊕ b) ⊕ c == a ⊕ (b ⊕ c). If at the same time you even have a unit element that is neutral with respect to ⊕, you have a monoid.

The important aspect of associativity is that you can arbitrarily group chunks of consecutive elements in a list, and ⊕ them in any order, since a ⊕ (b ⊕ (c ⊕ d)) == (a ⊕ b) ⊕ (c ⊕ d) - each bracket can be computed in parallel; then you'd need to "reduce" the "sums" of all brackets, and you've got your map-reduce sorted.

In order for this parallellisation to make sense, you need the chunking operation to be faster than ⊕ - otherwise, doing ⊕ sequentially is better than chunking. One such case is when you have a random access "list" - say, an array. [Data.Array.Repa](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Numeric_Haskell:_A_Repa_Tutorial) has plenty of parallellized folding functions.

If you are thinking of practicising to implement one yourself, you need to pick a good complex function ⊕ such that the benefit will show.

For example:

```
import Control.Parallel
import Data.List

pfold :: (Num a, Enum a) => (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
pfold _ [x] = x
pfold mappend xs  = (ys `par` zs) `pseq` (ys `mappend` zs) where
  len = length xs
  (ys', zs') = splitAt (len `div` 2) xs
  ys = pfold mappend ys'
  zs = pfold mappend zs'

main = print $ pfold (+) [ foldl' (*) 1 [1..x] | x <- [1..5000] ]
  -- need a more complicated computation than (+) of numbers
  -- so we produce a list of products of many numbers
```

Here I deliberately use a associative operation, which is called `mappend` only locally, to show it can work for a weaker notion than a monoid - only associativity matters for parallelism; since parallelism makes sense only for non-empty lists anyway, no need for `mempty`.

```
ghc -O2 -threaded a.hs
a +RTS -N1 -s
```

Gives 8.78 seconds total run time, whereas

```
a +RTS -N2 -s
```

Gives 5.89 seconds total run time on my dual core laptop. Obviously, no point trying more than -N2 on this machine.

Answer (score 3):

What you've described is essentially a monoid. In GHCI:

```
Prelude> :m + Data.Monoid
Prelude Data.Monoid> :info Monoid
class Monoid a where
  mempty :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mconcat :: [a] -> a
```

As you can see a monoid has three associated functions:

1. The `mempty` function is sort of like the identity function of the monoid. For example a `Num` can behave as a monoid apropos two operations: sum and product. For a sum `mempty` is defined as `0`. For a product `mempty` is defined as `1`.

   ```
   mempty `mappend` a = a
   a `mappend` mempty = a
   ```
2. The `mappend` function is similar to your `union` function. For exampe for a sum of `Num`s `mappend` is defined as `(+)` and for a product of `Num`s `mappend` is defined as `(*)`.
3. The `mconcat` function is similar to a fold. However because of the properties of a monoid it doesn't matter whether we fold from the left, fold from the right or fold from an arbitrary position. This is because `mappend` is supposed to be associative:

   ```
   (a `mappend` b) `mappend` c =  a `mappend` (b `mappend` c)
   ```

Note however that Haskell doesn't enforce the monoid laws. Hence if you make a type an instance of the `Monoid` typeclass then you're responsible to ensure that it satisfies the monoid laws.

In your case it's difficult to understand how `union` behaves from its type signature: `a -> a -> a`. Surely you can't make a type variable an instance of a typeclass. That's not allowed. You need to be more specific. What does `union` actually do?

To give you an example of how to make a type an instance of the monoid typeclass:

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }

instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
    mempty = 0
    mappend = (+)
```

That's it. We don't need to define the `mconcat` function because that has a default implementation that depends upon `mempty` and `mappend`. Hence when we define `mempty` and `mappend` we get `mconcat` for free.

Now you can use `Sum` as follows:

```
getSum . mconcat $ map Sum [1..6]
```

This is what's happening:

1. You're mapping the `Sum` constructor over `[1..6]` to produce `[Sum 1, Sum 2, Sum 3, Sum 4, Sum 5, Sum 6]`.
2. You give the resulting list to `mconcat` which folds it to `Sum 21`.
3. You use `getSum` to extract the `Num` from `Sum 21`.

Note however that the default implementation of `mconcat` is `foldr mappend mempty` (i.e. it's a right fold). For most cases the default implementation is sufficient. However in your case you might want to override the default implementation:

```
foldParallel :: Monoid a => [a] -> a
foldParallel []  = mempty
foldParallel [a] = a
foldParallel xs  = foldParallel left `mappend` foldParallel right
    where size = length xs
          index = (size + size `mod` 2) `div` 2
          (left, right) = splitAt index xs
```

Now we can create a new instance of `Monoid` as follows:

```
data Something a = Something { getSomething :: a }

instance Monoid (Something a) where
    mempty  = unionEmpty
    mappend = union
    mconcat = foldParallel
```

We use it as follows:

```
getSomething . mconcat $ map Something [1..6]
```

Note that I defined `mempty` as `unionEmpty`. I don't know what type of data the `union` function acts on. Hence I don't know what `mempty` should be defined as. Thus I'm simply calling it `unionEmpty`. Define it as you see fit.

Comment: I am not clear what is parallel about foldParallel. Using associativity law is only the enabler. You need to make sure splitting is faster than mappend, too.

Comment: Indeed. The additional overhead of splitting the list must be compensated by the time saved by executing the fold in parallel. Otherwise it won't make any sense to use `foldParallel` over a normal fold. There's nothing inherently parallel about the `foldParallel` function. However because it divides the list into two and processes each sub list recursively Haskell can make an optimization and process each sub list on a different core. Hence it enables parallelism. It doesn't guarantee it.

Comment: AFAIK GHC will never 'make an optimization and process each sub list on a different core'.  Parallelism is always explicit.

Comment: Parallel Term / Graph reduction is, of course, possible, but how much of it happens in practice? If some Haskell compiler does this without a hint, that would be a great example to add to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a long time after the OP, but I've just happened upon this and thought my experiences might be of help.

If we think about the problem, we can see that:

- A fold is essentially a function that takes a list of items, and converts them to a single item which may be the same type as the items in the list, but doesn't have to be: so its type is `([a] -> b)`.
- A parallel fold splits its input list into chunks, folds each chunk separately (in parallel), and then combines the results to derive the final result. For that we need:

  - A chunk size. This could be calculated with reference to the size of the input list, but that has a significant drawback: in order to determine the size of the list we have to process it, which loses the benefit of laziness. So it is better to make all chunks the same size; this could be hard-coded, but in a generic function it would be better to expose it as a parameter so that it can be varied and tuned to suit the needs of the calling application.
  - A function that knows how to combine results. This has the type `(b -> b -> b)`.

A suitable generic parallel fold function is thus:

```hs
import Control.Parallel

foldParallel :: Int -> ([a] -> b) -> (b -> b -> b) -> [a] -> b
foldParallel _ fold _ [] = fold []
foldParallel chunkSize fold combine xs = par lf $ combine lf rf
  where
    (left, right) = splitAt chunkSize xs
    lf = fold left
    rf = foldParallel chunkSize fold combine right
```

The parallel processing is done explicitly, using the `par` function which kicks off the evaluation of its first operand, in parallel, and returns the second operand.

It took a while - for an ancient, imperative-programming dinosaur like me - to get my head around the fact that the definitions in the `where` block don't actually evaluate anything, but just set up things that can be evaluated; hence the fold named as `lf` can be referenced in both operands of `par` but is only evaluated once.

The difference that `par` makes is that if the function just returns `combine lf rf`, when that is evaluated `lf` needs to be evaluated, then `rf`, then `combine lf rf`. But `par lf $ combine lf rf` means that `lf` is already wholly or partly evaluated (in parallel) by the time its value is needed. And because `rf` is itself a parallel fold, the same is true of the folding of each subsequent chunk.