# How to parallelize a fold with Parallel Evaluation Strategies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Is it possible to create a parallel fold with Parallel Evaluation Strategies (`Control.Parallel.Strategies`) in Haskell, when the fold function is associative (e.g. addition)?

My idea was to split the list into chunks, but how should the (optimal) chunk size be calculated? Is there a generic way?

Comment: Do you mean associative?

Comment: @Alec commutativity would suffice for my needs (e.g. non-deterministic execution and combination order of parallel sparks)

Comment: Ummm... Are you sure? If your function is not associative, you will need to tell us the order in which operations occur (where to place the brackets) and that will almost certainly constrain considerably any parallel fold.

Comment: @Alec yes, you are right. It is better to require an associative function.

Comment: I think your question might be tightly related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117922/parallel-folding-in-haskell (or better to it's great answer)

Comment: @Carsten is (very) different when your hard computation is each element (as in your reference) or whole list; if the former, muffel has no problem (how to know chunk size) if the later, muffel want to know the split size (but your referred solution not solve).

Comment: @muffel I think you must to use repa (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) or other for intensive parallel computations and Carsten reference for individual hard computations.

Comment: @josejuan sounds great, I'll definitely try it, thank you