# Drastically different run times for folding a list

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I'm adding up elements in a ring. For the purpose of this post, I'll use rational numbers:

```
intList n = map (\x -> [x]) [1 .. n]

toReciprocal xs = map (\x -> [[1], x]) xs

addFrac [[a], [b]] [[c], [d]] = let num = a*d + b*c
                                    denom = b*d
                                    g = gcd num denom
                                in [[num `div` g], [denom `div` g]]

addFracs xs
    | length xs == 1 = head xs
    | otherwise = (head xs) `addFrac` (addFracs $ tail xs)

main = print $ addFracs $ toReciprocal $ intList 20000
```

I understand this is not how you would want to add rational numbers, but my ring is a little complicated and this is the simplest case that replicates the issue I'm seeing. The above code is really slow (~11.0 seconds on my dekstop), so motivated by this post ([parallel "Folding" in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117922/parallel-folding-in-haskell)) I decided to try:

```
parAddFracs xs
    | len == 1 = head xs
    | otherwise = (ys `par` zs) `pseq` (ys `addFrac` zs)
    where len = length xs
          (ys', zs') = splitAt (len `div` 2) xs
          ys = parAddFracs ys'
          zs = parAddFracs zs'

main = print $ parAddFracs $ toReciprocal $ intList 20000
```

and this returns almost immediately (~0.1 seconds), even when I don't compile with -threaded.

I tried increasing the number of fractions to 2000000

```
main = print $ parAddFracs $ toReciprocal $ intList 2000000
```

and compiling with -threaded, +RTS -N1 runs in ~17.8 seconds and +RTS -N4 runs in ~15.6 seconds. When running with +RTS -N4 I see the cpu usage is between ~120% and ~350%, but despite the increased cpu usage, there just seems to be very little improvement in running time.

**Question 1:** Why does using parAddFracs run so much faster (orders of magnitude) than addFracs, even when I'm not compiling with threading support?

Edit: @DanielWagner points out that this speed difference is due to the difference in the order of evaluation between the two. I'm still unsure of the answer to Question 2.

**Question 2:** When compiling with threading support, why does moving from +RTS -N1 to +RTS -N4 seem to have little effect on the running time, even though it seems to have a great effect on the amount of processing power used?

Thanks!

Comment: A conjecture: `Integer` operations like multiplication and addition are slightly faster when the two operands are closer in size. Perhaps this happens more often when doing a divide-and-conquer (as in your second solution) than when operating front-to-back (as in your first solution).

Comment: Quick update: in my tests, `fold (+) 0 [1/x | x <- [1..20000]] :: Rational` is indeed much faster when using `fold = foldb` than `fold = foldl'`, where `foldb` is the "tree-fold" that repeatedly combines adjacent pairs until the list has only one element. (`foldb f z [] = z; foldb f z [x] = x; foldb f z xs = foldb f z (pairwise f xs); pairwise f (x:y:rest) = f x y : pairwise f rest; pairwise f other = other`)

Comment: Get rid of the use of `length` in both examples.  It's slow and ugly.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're right that this explains the case in the code I posted. In fact, foldb runs significantly faster than a naive fold on my original code, although parAddFracs is still twice as fast as foldb when adding the elements of my ring (where the coefficients of my objects are never very large). Edit: Any idea why threading it seems to take up so much cpu, but doesn't increase in speed? I originally thought the overhead of creating the threads might negate the extra cpus, but the link I mentioned in the post seemed to get a hefty increase in speed when simply adding numbers.

Comment: @augustss In the second example, could you provide a suggestion on how to split a list in half without using length? I understand how I can remove it in the first example.

Comment: @EddyJD If your ring is commutative the approach I used in `pairwise` works for splitting a list in two without computing the length. e.g. something like `split [] = ([], []); split (x:xs) = let (ls, rs) = split xs in (x:rs, ls)`.

Comment: This seems to run a fair bit slower than using length in my setting and runs just a little bit slower than using length in the posted code. Ugly or not, I'll need to keep it. I'm still trying to figure out why parallelism here isn't speeding things up.

Comment: If splitting in half is important then a list is the wrong data structure.